# Is there a word to refer to a group of people who have mutual negative feelings for a certain person or thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, a word to refer to a group of people who discriminate against something/someone. Something that is more unique than, say, plain sexism/racism.

Pretty much a word like cult, but not specific to religion.

Example:

> Are you really part of this ____?

Comment: I am having trouble with the word group here. I am not convinced the OP really means group. We  just say: sexists, racists, etc.

Comment: @JOSH I mean a word to describe a group of people. Like to collectively call a group of people by.

Comment: "Are you really part of this ism?"

Comment: If you want a word like "cult" just use "cult". Cult isn't strictly specific to religion; see for example "cult of personality".

Comment: @DougWarren that sounds about right.

Comment: There are plenty of words for a closed or exclusive group of people: clique, cult, etc.  Are you searching for a word that emphasizes the hate, or that emphasizes the group?  A bunch of sports fans who happen to hate team X, but do not otherwise have anything else in common?

Comment: @MarkBeadles According to Google's definition, "a system of religious veneration and devotion directed towards a particular figure or object" The other results look quite similar. I guess you could also use that though, it might just be a bit confusing.

Comment: @JohnFeltz The former :)

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus "Are you really one of those whatever-haters?"

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus See the second bullet point: a misplaced or excessive admiration for a particular person or thing. "a cult of personality surrounding the leaders" synonyms: obsession with, fixation on, mania for, passion for, idolization of, devotion to, worship of, veneration of "the cult of eternal youth in Hollywood"

Comment: @JohnFeltz I was hoping to have it usable in a sentence like: Did you really form a "cult" against me? (and yes, I am the object who is seen in a negative light)

Comment: Well then it's both the group and the hate.  "Conspiracy" would fit.

Comment: "Are you really a bigot?" (an application of an adjective implies membership of a group: e.g. 'the red man' says the man is part of the group of red things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example sentence should be:

> Are you really part of that ____?

Also, cult does not have to be specific to a religion, but I guess you still don't want that word which is fine.

How about the word creed?

> a set of beliefs or aims which guide someone's actions.

Answer (score 1):

The word "**ism**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ism) as

> A distinctive practice, system, or philosophy, typically a political
>   ideology or an artistic movement.

The entry notes that the term is considered "informal" and "derogatory".

Answer (score 0):

> **lynch mob** (noun)
>
> 1. a group of people who condemn and punish a person without a fair trial.
>      *He claimed that they had been the victims of a racist lynch mob.*
> 2. **a group of people who criticize someone severely and try to bring about the person's downfall**
>      *Something approaching a lynch mob has been gathering against the Chancellor for even daring to consider higher interest rates.*
>      *It is in the public interest that sleaze is exposed. But it's time to call off the lynch mob.*
>
> — [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lynch-mob)